# AWS S3 listBuckets returns null, using node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using node js I'm trying to list the buckets I have in my AWS S3 by following this basic examples.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html

My code looks like this, and is runned from localhost.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk"),
    con = require('./../lib/config.js');

var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: con.fig.AWSAccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: con.fig.AWSSecretKey,
});

s3.listBuckets(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But data is null.

What have I missed?
Is there some permission to set? I have set the permission AmazonS3FullAccess on the user.

I want to be able to upload files from a website to a S3 bucket.

Comment: have you tried to print your err out to console to see if an error message is being thrown?.  ie if(err) console.log(err)

Comment: Yes I have. The only thing is says is 'null'

Comment: Are you attempting this locally, on an ec2 instance, in Lambda or something else?

Comment: Yes I'm (I was) trying get all my buckets on a S3 from a localhost. I have added full S3 access on the user. But I can write files to a bucket an that enough for what I want to do right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  The documentation says if err is null then the request was successful.

```
s3.listBuckets(function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listBuckets-property

ok load your config using the following

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk"),
con = require('./../lib/config.js');
AWS.config.update({
   accessKeyId: con.fig.AWSAccessKeyId,
   secretAccessKey: con.fig.AWSSecretKey
}) 

var s3 = new AWS.S3(); 
s3.listBuckets(function(err,data){ 
  if(err)console.log(err); 
  else console.log (data)
});
```

Comment: This is realy anoying. When I print out data it's 'null'. When I print out error it's says. 

{ [XMLParserError: Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char: {]
  message: 'Non-whitespace before first tag.\nLine: 0\nColumn: 1\nChar: {',
  code: 'XMLParserError',
  retryable: true,
  time: Thu Oct 20 2016 17:04:10 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  originalError:
   { message: 'Non-whitespace before first tag.\nLine: 0\nColumn: 1\nChar: {',
     code: 'XMLParserError',
     retryable: true,
     time: Thu Oct 20 2016 17:04:10 GMT+0200 (CEST) },
  statusCode: 500 }

Comment: ok load your config using the following AWS.config.update({accessKeyId:'keyId', secretAccessKey:'secretAccessKey'})

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.listBuckets(function(err,data){ if(err)console.log(err); else console.log data});

Comment: I have updated a second part to the solution above.  This is what I currently have for my app and it works.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I still can't get this to work so I have to look into some other solution.